# How to do File chain and working with its content in Python

Tags: python, list, file, filenames

I'm pretty new to Python, and I got this homework which consists in defining a function that sets up a filename chain; meaning that every file contains in its first line the filename of the next file that has to be opened. So opening up the file A.txt I can read in its first line the name of the file B.txt, and so on. It is a "loop" of filenames. Such a loop should end when the last file to be opened contains the first file's name (i.e. the input file). If A.txt is given as an input, it contains the name `B.txt`, which contains the name `C.txt`, but this one contains the name `A.txt`.

Basically, I have to open all the files, read the first line containing the next file path and stop when the last file leads back to the first one (i.e. We have in input File A.txt that leads to B.txt that leads to C.txt, finally C.txt leads back to A.txt).

Every file contains, besides the name of the next file path, other words which have to be put into a separate list.

I can NOT import any libraries, it is a requirement of the homework.

I managed to get such words in a list but only for the first file, but I don't know how to access the other files using this specific logic (the loop from above).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This sounds like a complete enough description to start writing code, so break it down into its component steps ("load file given a filename in a variable", and "read a line from file into a variable") and then compose those actions.